# Why is LDAP "memberUid" restricted to ascii, but "uid" is not?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache-ds

I'm getting this error from ApacheDS (2.0.0-M21):

```
ERR_04447_CANNOT_NORMALIZE_VALUE Cannot normalize the wrapped value ERR_04473_NOT_VALID_VALUE Not a valid value 'gu\C3\AApes' for the AttributeType 'attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.12 NAME 'memberUid'
```

when trying to "ldapadd" an LDIF entry like:

```
# Admins, Groups, example.com
dn: cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: Admins
gidNumber: 10002
description: Group account
memberUid: john
memberUid: gu\C3\AApes
```

The user imported fine (see below).

I guess the problem is that "memberUid" must be ascii "String(IA5)" while "uid" is allowed to be Unicode. It seems MS Active Directory's schema is the same:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677101(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680508(v=vs.85).aspx

Why wouldn't "memberUid" be the same type as "uid"?

```
# guêpes, people, example.com
dn: uid=gu\C3\AApes,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
postalCode: 31000
shadowFlag: 0
uidNumber: 1000
title: System Administrator
initials: JD
shadowWarning: 7
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
shadowMin: 8
o: Example
l: Toulouse
shadowLastChange: 10877
gidNumber: 10000
shadowMax: 999999
shadowExpire: -1
userPassword: password
#mail: gu\C3\AApes@example.com
#homeDirectory: /home/gu\C3\AApes
homeDirectory: /home/guepes
cn: Spanish
sn: Wasp
displayName: Spanish Wasp
gecos: Spanish Wasp
givenName: SpanishWasp
```